# What's the meaning of this line beneath inflated view variables?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently updated Android Studio to 2.1.2, and also enabled Java8. But since then, there's a line beneath all of inflated view variables like this:

[image]

There's no explanation whatsoever.

Since I'm usually obsessed to eliminate all the warnings, these bother me that I can't do anything.

Comment: hovering over it doesn't show anything?

Comment: @rid, no. Not even in right click context menu, and nothing at the bar at scrollbar.